# Are there browser/system security measures that can block Unity WebGL projects?

Tags: c#, html, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

**The PROBLEM**

I am currently building a simple website containing Unity WebGL projects for a client. The games are working on all browsers for me, my teammates, and my producer, but one of the games does NOT work for our client (on any browser, Mac, or Windows).

All the games are embedded in a div in the exact same manner. There are no discernible differences between the build settings or output for each of the games. Unfortunately, I only have access to the Unity project for the game that is not loading for the client.

**THE CLUES**

While on a call with the client where he shared his problems, he specified the game in question did not load at all in Chrome (not even a rectangle appeared) and crashed in Safari (rectangle appeared first). The other games on the website loaded for him normally. Over the course of the conversation, he mentioned that he could not share his screen due to security limitations/software on his device from work. All of the games are built with 2019.4.15f1.

The only odd thing happening on my end is that the Unity logo is not appearing while the game loads as it typically does for games w/the free license.

**THE QUESTION**

Are there any settings or known problems within Unity for WebGL that can cause this type of issue? Due to the fact the other games work fine for him, I suspect there is some setting in my build that is causing it to trigger his security. Thank you for any and all suggestions!

Edit: We are hoping to avoid asking our client to print and share their console, just to maintain professionalism.

Comment: "software on his device" - i'd start with that. and let the clients IT people take a look at that. also: you _could_ explain to the client how to access the browser console's output and send you debugging details.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Franz. We are hoping it doesn't come to that, just to maintain a good appearance for our team. It is difficult to suggest it is a problem on their end, as the other games are working normally.

Comment: just my opinion, but _asking your client for debugging details to help solve his problem_ is not a lack of professionalism, but the definition of professionalism. it demonstrates you are focused on solving the problem, _not_ only on keeping your face. and after all: in order to _fix_ something, you need to know what's _broken_.

Comment: That's true :) The producer's decision in the end, not mine unfortunately.

Comment: Is the content hosted by a web server or are you having them load it from a local filesystem e.g. with a `file://` url?

Comment: It is hosted for staging on our company dev server (pretty sure it is Apache)

Comment: Is this a new build compared to the others ef is it using unitys new compression aa that needs changes in iis and Apache